# MS Access 2016 refer to multiple text boxes with same name but different suffix (e.g. Cal1... Cal33)

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

I have a simple for/next loop, to evaluate 33 form memo fields (calendar boxes) (Cal1... Cal33) against two combo ctrls (cbofrom and cboto).  The cbo values are simply 1 though 33.  The purpose is to simply move text from one memo field to another memo field if the memo field (Cal1... Cal33) equals cboto:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 33
i = 1
If Me.Cal&(i) = Me.cboto Then Me.Cal&(i) = me.cal & Me.cbofrom
Next I
```

VBA doesn't appear to want to concantenate the name of the field (Cal1... Cal33) as a means of looping.   Any suggestions would be helpful.
[Added an image of the calendar layout - See block 5 (Cal5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGIJL.jpg)

Comment: It seems that it wouldn't know what Me.Cal is since that's not a control on your form. So it probably doesn't know what to concatenate with the (i). Maybe Me."Cal"&(i) or something like that would work.

Comment: Reference the control by its name in the form's `Controls` collection: `Me.Controls("Cal" & i)`

Comment: Is `me.cal` in `me.cal & Me.cbofrom` correct, or was it supposed to be one of those `Cal1` thru `Cal33` items?

Comment: HansUp,  me.cal is the root name and is correct with the & me.cbofrom adding the value 1 thru 33 for a complete name of Cal1 (for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a control by its name in the form's `Controls` collection.
So `Me.Controls("Cal" & 27)` is the same control as `Me.Cal27`

```vb
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 33
    'i = 1 ' do not change the value of your loop variable here
    With Me.Controls("Cal" & i)
        If .Value = Me!cboto.Value Then
            .Value = Me.Controls("Cal" & Me!cbofrom.Value).Value
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Making progress; it did not error out, but the values did not yet switch - let me step through it....

Comment: steps through properly; is very clean, but Cal1 does not change its value to Cal4's value  (using those two as a test); Let me test non-loop.

Comment: Non-loop explicit works great under the With/Endwith - nice.   Now just need to make the loop work.

Comment: Tried a couple things, but will not work as a loop (explicit works fine).   Logic is good, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: When you're stepping thru the code line by line and get inside the `If` block, double-check what `"Cal" & Me!cbofrom.Value` gives you and also double-check the value of that control.  Also check `Me.Controls("Cal" & i).Value` immediately before and after attempting to change its value.

Comment: Back at it on different PC; unable to step (probably since I'm in a form and not in a module).   I'll have to pick this back up in the a.m.   Thanks so far HansUp!   I'm confident we'll get this.

Comment: HansUp,  all is working now, thank you.   I debugged and found (embarrassingly) that the bound column of cboto was reading the index, not the control value.  Once I changed the bound column, the procedure works just fine.    Thank you for all the help.  I learned to use me.controls properly.